# JW Player event at specified second

Tags: javascript, events, jwplayer

Does JW Player support events which fires a function at specified second only?
I found no info in the docu.

It should work like this:

```
jwplayer().atTime(5, functions(){  /* do something */  })
jwplayer().atTime(9, functions(){  /* do something */  })
```

Comment: Tried http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/javascript-interaction/15680/events-not-working-if-if-statement-has-2-conditions/ maybe it's help you

Comment: The event is called onTime().

Sample code:

<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("player").setup({
            file: "bunny.mp4",
            flashplayer: "player.swf",
            height: 300,
            width: 465,
   events:{
    onTime: function(event) {
     if (event.position >= 5) {
      this.pause();
      window.location = "http://www.google.com";
     }
    }
   }
    });
</script>

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you ethan from longtail. i solved it with with "setTimeout(1000) & parseInt(getPosition())". Am i right, that this variant is more efficient than the native onTime event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event is 
**onTime(callback)**
While the player is playing, this event is fired as the playback position gets updated.This may occur as frequently as 10 times per second.

Event attributes:

**duration**: Number: Duration of the current item in seconds.

**offset**: Number: When playing streaming media, this value contains the last unbuffered seek offset.

**position**: Number: Playback position in seconds.

For more events:
[JWPlayer Events and more](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12540/javascript-api-reference#Events)